# Request Headers vs Response Headers

Tags: apache, caching, http-headers, request-headers, response-headers

I am trying to get an image to cache on a website. The image is served by PHP in which I am setting a response header of cache control with the appropriate value, however this is not caching the image, I think it might have something to do with the request header having a cache control of no-cache? Headers below:

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:max-age=290304000, public
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:5166
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Thu, 28 Jan 2016 15:50:56 GMT
Etag:f31a1f9f6699e0660c6b0b8e2c133add
Expires:Sat, 27 Feb 2016 15:50:56 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 26 Nov 2015 11:40:11 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.17
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic dGs6dGs=
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_dc_gtm_UA-60001243-5=1; _gat_UA-60001243-5=1; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkdcL0VYYUxMNEU0Q1wvM1VvQlpOU3NDZz09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJWaGVDaVJqdGdMaWlOaDBzUTI5Tzd3TmE1SU9UR2VcL29ZallVSWR6TUtaVTMyclM1aWpmM0F6Tk94eFBCZjZzamQ1U05RdlR0WTNUZzdFMEFLMkZYVFE9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijg3MjY1ZDM3MDI1ZTRmYTI0ODY3NWYxNDEyM2RkMGRhMWFlY2E3NDFjOGEwMTQ1NzZiMWZmODFkNzZjNzRhYWQifQ%3D%3D; _ga=GA1.4.5501114.1453888035
Host:*****.com
Pragma:no-cache
Host:*****.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
```

How do I get these images to cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea about the lack of caching happening because of the `Cache-Control: no-cache` *request* header is correct; that request header tells any possible caches along the way to **not** use any cached data for the requested resource (see the "End-to-end reload" section of [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4)).

To be specific, your response *may* actually be being cached.  But that `Cache-Control: no-cache` header in the *request* says that that particular HTTP client does not want to take advantage of the cache; another HTTP client may be able to use the cached resource.

For situations like there, where some HTTP clients refuse to use any cache, I've seen *e.g.* haproxy used to filter out/rewrite that `Cache-Control` request header; I suspect that Apache could be used to do the same.  In theory such rewriting of request headers behind the client's back, so to speak, is not a good idea.  But if you really do need such requests using the cache where available, it may be the expedient solution.

Hope this helps!