# Wrong cache-control headers delivered from Google Cloud Storage / Google Cloud CDN static website - how to fix?

Tags: caching, google-cloud-storage, cache-control, pagespeed-insights, google-cloud-cdn

I have a static web site hosted on a bucket in Google Cloud Storage with Google Cloud CDN in front of it. That site has many [pictures with inspirational quotes](https://discoverquotes.com/inspirational/) on them.

[PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscoverquotes.com%2F) is saying they need an efficient cache policy:

[image]

but I am setting a cache time of one year (Cache-Control:"Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000") on all my images when I use gsutil to upload them to my bucket.

If I go to the bucket and check, it says they are properly set:
[image: the object metadata edit screen in google cloud storage]

and if I check my settings for Google Cloud CDN, also set to one year across the board:
[image: screen shot of google cloud cdn settings showing one year cache time]

But PageSpeed Insights says:

> Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy 15 resources found
> A long cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page.

I check the actual Response headers delivered via Chrome Dev Tools and they look ok:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 46890
alt-svc: clear
cache-control: Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000,public
content-language: en
content-length: 10008
content-type: image/webp
date: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 06:16:37 GMT
etag: "36fd43e7d25b661ac7172364222c3d5c"
last-modified: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 21:41:02 GMT
server: UploadServer
x-goog-generation: 1643060462624518
x-goog-hash: crc32c=6URgQQ==
x-goog-hash: md5=Nv1D59JbZhrHFyNkIiw9XA==
x-goog-metageneration: 1
x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
x-goog-stored-content-length: 10008
x-guploader-uploadid: ADPycds_8JRi-oDTLk2qZyVndksOR3St2XzntoPRTq-56j6QQNI3ebAzS1h4FkuifRhOiJcLRYq-Lo2cNmTpnzHVnsE
```

although the Request Headers do not:

```
    :authority: discoverquotes.com
:method: GET
:path: /love/love-titlepin400.webp
:scheme: https
accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: _ga=GA1.1.445449550.1642877186; _ga_8WVC1J4HD6=GS1.1.1643137529.32.1.1643137574.0
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://discoverquotes.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: image
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36
```

But it is only the response headers I can control right? And I cannot really know what Request Headers PageSpeed Insights is setting when they fetch it, right? or ?

I see this issue on stackoverflow: [Request Headers vs Response Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066245/request-headers-vs-response-headers)

but do not see how to fix the request headers being sent? Is PageSpeed Insights fetching pages themselves or using my browser?

I am confused. Suggestions to debug, learn more, or fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you've written the phrase `Cache-Control` in the `Cache-Control` configuration field, causing it to appear twice in response header, making it invalid. Presumably setting it to simply `public, max-age=31536000` will make the resulting header valid.

Don't worry abut the request `Cache-Control` headers, you can't control them anyway. They're probably set that way because Dev Tools usually turns caching off.

Comment: That was it, fixed, thank YOU!!!!  Now to figure out how I did that using gsutil.